# Утечка памяти Custom ImageView Android

Tags: android, memory, imageview

Задача в том что бы создать кастомный макет из изображений. Создал такой класс который будет ресайзить изображения под конкретный экран, не теряя при этом их качества. Но теперь конкретные утечки памяти. Кто что подскажет?

```
public class ResizebleImageView extends ImageView {
private Activity mActivity;
private float mCoeficient;

public ResizebleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mActivity = (Activity) context;
    mCoeficient = getCoeficient();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    System.out.println("Bytes per drawable " + ((BitmapDrawable)getDrawable()).getBitmap().getByteCount());
    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
    if (drawable != null) {
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height;

        if (MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        } else {
            height = (int) Math.ceil((float) width * (float) drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / (float) drawable.getIntrinsicWidth());
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

private float getCoeficient() {
    DisplayMetrics ds = new DisplayMetrics();
    mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(ds);
    int screenWidth = ds.widthPixels;

    return screenWidth / 750f;
}

public void configureView(int width, int height, int leftMargin, int topMargin) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (width * mCoeficient), (int) (height * mCoeficient));
    params.leftMargin = (int)(leftMargin * mCoeficient);
    params.topMargin = (int)(topMargin * mCoeficient);

    this.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

}

Вот вызов метода из активити этого класса из активити. изображений как видно не так много, а их размер становиться колосальным.

```
    sticks.configureView(459, 410, 106, 1610);/.ну и таких вызовов 7 штук для разных вьюх с разными размерами.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это не утечка памяти(вы же не теряете ссылок на объекты), а истощение памяти - OutOfMemory(OOM).

Возникает при попытке загрузки внутрь ImageView содержимого, от которого компонент может подавиться.

Ваша реализация, по сути, вообще не требует особых дополнительных выделений памяти. Так, эта строчка, например, просто копирует ссылку на уже имеющийся в памяти объект:

```
Drawable drawable = getDrawable(); // OOM
```

Проблема в том, что размер ресурсов(изображения) в байтах может быть существенно больше, чем имеется в распоряжении у приложения: например, если размер изображения, помещаемого в ImageView, очень большого размера, то объем используемой для визуального отображения памяти будет сильно расти. Понаблюдайте за поведением GC в отладочной панели наблюдения за памятью приложения.

Вот, например, использование памяти при отображении 1 изображения размером 480х360:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То же изображение 1280х960:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То же изображение 2048х1460:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е скорее всего, ваша проблема заключается в использовании "непричесанных" графических ресурсов - несжатых и неотмасшабированных.

Comment: Да, в этом вы правы. Я это и так понимал, но вот как бы обработать эти изображения? скажем так, те изображения что тянут у меня много памяти находятся у меня в drawables. Получать битмап и обрабатывать его ?

Comment: Bitmap при неправильной конфигурации пиксела (да и в целом) "съест" еще больше памяти. ImageView по умолчанию конфигурируется под масштабирование содержимого(насколько помню, свойство scaleType), поэтому создавать кастомный класс лишь для этих целей нет необходимости. В крайнем случае перенесите ответственность за рутину масшабирования на библиотеку Picasso, например, и используйте её, но опять же, "причесав" размеры ресурсов. Здесь стоит понимать, что ресайз изображения - в любом случае ресурсоемкая операция.

Comment: Ну фишка в том, что у меня есть макет из изображений. Изначально они занимаают немного памяти, и эти изображения нужно разместить по макету согласно заданных координат. Я пробовал вручную рассчитать размеры в DP но как то у меня не очень вышло. Я брал размер этих картинок для конкретного экрана и отсюда рассчитывал DP. В конечном итоге все было криво. Возможно подскажете как рассчитать эти размеры в DP что бы было одинаково на всех экранах

Comment: Возможно, абсолютный размер в DP может стать хорошим решением в борьбе с OOM, но не факт. Еще может быть, что вам и вовсе стоит отказаться от использования ImageView в проектировании своего интерфейса, перейдя на WebView(что тоже тяжеловесно, в общем-то). Не получится сказать что-то конкретное - зависит от вашей задачи.